# How to set profile for Spring Application to be used in Minikube

Tags: spring-boot, minikube

I am deploying a Spring boot application to a local Minikube cluster. The local deployment needs a complete set of configuration. Where do I give the information, that a specific profile for Spring Boot is to be used instead of the standard application.yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set an environment variable to tell the container which profile is going to be active:

```
  containers:
  - name: ...
    image: ...:1.0
    env:
    - name: spring_profiles_active
      value: dev
```

and put your alternative configuration into `application-dev.yaml`.

Alternatively, without using profiles, you can tell Spring to use which properties file with `spring.config.location` property:

```
  containers:
  - name: ...
    image: ...:1.0
    env:
    - name: spring_config_location
      value: /path/to/your/alterinative/configuration
```